# Multiple Custom Checkboxes (HTML) - how to get them to respond separately from one another

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to reformat the checkboxes in one of my projects to fit the design of the UI better, but I'm struggling to get the checkboxes to react separately. When I click the lower box, the upper box checks/unchecks and nothing happens in the lower box. This could probably be resolved by adding IDs to the checkboxes but (a) I'm unsure where to put the ID tag, and (b) eventually this HTML will have to be created dynamically using javascript as these are containers for elements in a task managing app.

I'd also like for the div with class redbox to change colors when the checkbox is clicked, but that's a slightly less pressing issue. If you know how to resolve either of these issues I'd really appreciate your help!

Code:
(I think I included all relevant code but if something's still missing please let me know!)

(CSS)

```
.taskspacer{
  height:5px;
}
.taskout{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
.taskcontain{
  width:calc(100% - 2px);
  height:100px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
.redbox{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f53240;
  float:left;
  padding:0;
}
.infobox{
  float:right;
  height:100px;
  width:calc(100% - 101px);

}
input[type=checkbox]{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.check{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align:center;
}
.check label{
  cursor: pointer;
  position:absolute;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
.check label:after{
  opacity:0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 13px;
  left: 13px;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.check label:hover::after{
  opacity:0.4;
}
.check input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after{
  opacity:1;
}
```

(HTML)

```
<div class="taskout">
              <div class="taskcontain">
                <div class="redbox">
                <!--center checkbox-->
                  <div class="check">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" name="">
                    <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="infobox">
                  <!--task information-->
                  <div class = "date"></div>
                  <div class = "taskname"></div>
                  <div class = "bigname"></div>
                  <div class = "bigdate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <div class="taskout">
              <div class="taskcontain">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="taskout">
              <div class="taskcontain">
                <div class="redbox">
                  <!--center checkbox-->
                  <div class="check">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" name="">
                    <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div id="infobox">
                  <!--task information-->
                  <div class = "date"></div>
                  <div class = "taskname"></div>
                  <div class = "bigname"></div>
                  <div class = "bigdate"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="height:5px;"></div>
            <div class="taskout">
              <div class="taskcontain">

              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: also I'm aware it's a little broken with the infobox divs but that's not my main concern right now lol

Comment: Checkboxes do not behave as you describe unless there is some sort of javascript in play that forces it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the same ID for both your checkboxes. ID's need to be **unique** on the page and cannot be repeated. You have invalid markup and thats why it behaving odd.

Simply change the the `id` and the matching `<label>`'s `for` attribute to a new id and it will work as expected.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput2">
<label for="checkboxInput2"></label>
```

See below:

```css
.taskspacer {
  height: 5px;
}

.taskout {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.taskcontain {
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.redbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #f53240;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

.infobox {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(100% - 101px);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.check {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.check label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.check label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 13px;
  left: 13px;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.check label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.check input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="taskout">
  <div class="taskcontain">
    <div class="redbox">
      <!--center checkbox-->
      <div class="check">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput">
        <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infobox">
      <!--task information-->
      <div class="date"></div>
      <div class="taskname"></div>
      <div class="bigname"></div>
      <div class="bigdate"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<div class="taskout">
  <div class="taskcontain">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="taskout">
  <div class="taskcontain">
    <div class="redbox">
      <!--center checkbox-->
      <div class="check">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput2">
        <label for="checkboxInput2"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infobox">
      <!--task information-->
      <div class="date"></div>
      <div class="taskname"></div>
      <div class="bigname"></div>
      <div class="bigdate"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height:5px;"></div>
<div class="taskout">
  <div class="taskcontain">

  </div>
</div>
```